# Error trying to launch ADBView sublime plugin

Tags: android, adb, sublimetext3

```
Error trying to launch ADB:

['adb', 'devices']

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "adbview in /home/username/.config/sublime-text-3/Installed Packages/ADBView.sublime-package", line 415, in run
  File "./subprocess.py", line 824, in __init__
  File "./subprocess.py", line 1448, in _execute_child
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'adb'
```

**environment:** Ubuntu 14.04

Android SDK is installed, adb is added to the PATH and works ok from the terminal

ADBView installed via PackageControl